# How to use my custmize test-engine in junit5 only?

Tags: junit5

I had build a new TestEngine which can suppert the cases run in a parallelStream so that run faster.But when i launch,the default test-engine:jupiter-engine will run。So my cases will run 2 times. What should i do to stop the jupiter-engine run?

When i debug the junit5 source code,i see the DefaultLauncher will find two engine.

This is the source code:

```
DefaultLauncher(Iterable testEngines) { Preconditions.condition(testEngines != null && testEngines.iterator().hasNext(), () -> "Cannot create Launcher without at least one TestEngine; " + "consider adding an engine implementation JAR to the classpath"); this.testEngines = validateUniqueIds(testEngines); }
```

this is the launch code:

```
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = 
LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request() .selectors(selectPackage("mytest) ) .filters( includeClassNamePatterns("^.*TestCase?$") ).configurationParameter() .build();

Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create(); // Register a listener of your choice TestExecutionListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener(); launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
```

Comment: Did you try the built-in parallel execution support described at https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution ?

Comment: No. I'm useing the version of 5.0.2.So i build a new testEngine。And now i had find a config to run the true engine,thanks